# Extjs 4.1 - Listerning in CellEditing plugin not working at second time

Tags: extjs, tree, extjs4.1, treegrid

i define a **treeGrid** with plugin CellEditing like

```
Ext.define('MyExample', {
        extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',   
        id: 'example',
        alias: 'example',
        ....
        plugins: [
            Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                clicksToEdit: 1,
                listeners: {
                    beforeedit: function(plugin, edit){
                        alert('don't run second time');
                    }
                }
            })
        ],
        ...
```

And i have a **button** when i click this button will call below window (this window has treeGrid above)

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
title: 'Phân xử lý',
modal:true,
height: 500
width: 500
layout: 'border',
...
item[
 {
  title: 'example',
  region: 'center',
  xtype: 'example', // that here
  layout: 'fit'
 }
]
```

Everything working at first time but when i close the window at first time and click button to call window again then CellEditting still working but listeners not working ?

How to fix that thanks

**EDIT**

Please see my example code in **http://jsfiddle.net/E6Uss/**

In first time when i click button. Everything working well like
[image]

But when i close Example window and open it again I try click to blocked cell again i get a bug like
[image]

How to fix this bug? thanks

Comment: create plugin on `initComponent` of panel

Comment: @MMT i try init initComponent: function () {} but error is (TypeError: a is undefined ext-all.js line 21) ?

Comment: @MMT Can u fix my code? i try to add initComponent but i think initComponent not exsit ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using **Ext.create** inside the plugins array for the tree grid. This have the effect of creating it once and attaching the result adhoc to your defined class.

If you close the window, all the resources within the window are destroyed. The second time you instantiate the tree panel, the plugin is not there. Take a look at this fiddle : I see what your issue is. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/jdflores/E6Uss/1/

```
     {
        ptype : 'cellediting',
        clicksToEdit: 1,
        listeners: {
            beforeedit: function(plugin, edit){
                console.log('EDITOR');
                if (edit.record.get('block')) {
                    alert('this cell have been blocked');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Upvote for clarifying my answer.  Although I think that in a practical sense, my answer is probably the best route overall.

Comment: Thank u that's working. I found some question and it's problem is cellediting and them using initComponent function. I try create initComponent function but fail. I think TreeGrid hasn't initComponent function?

Answer (score 1):

You're recreating the window on every click of the button.  This recreation may be messing with your configuration objects or destroying associations or references within them, or something similar.  Try to reuse the window everytime by replacing your button code with something like:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Click me',
        visible: false,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

        handler: function(button) {
            if(!button.myWindow)
            {
                button.myWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                   title: 'Example',
                   height     : 300,
                   width      : 500,
                   layout: 'border',
                   closeAction: 'hide',
                   items: [{            
                            region: 'center',
                            floatable:false,
                            layout:'fit',
                            xtype: 'example',
                            margins:'1 1 1 1'
                        }
                    ]
                 });
            }
            button.myWindow.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it needed complete the editing cell, try finish it:

```
...
beforeedit: function(plugin, edit){
     alert('don't run second time');
     plugin.completeEdit();
}
```

Sencha: [CompleteEdit](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing-method-completeEdit)

Comment: i try like in my code: plugin.completeEdit(); if (edit.record.get('block'))return false; but don't working :(

Answer (score -1):

I put together a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jdflores/6vJZf/1/

I think the problem with your column is that it's dataIndex is expecting that the editor value  be a boolean type (because 'block' was set as datIndex instead of 'date'). I assume you are using the 'block' field just to identify which are blocked to be edited. I modified the fidle provided here: http://jsfiddle.net/jdflores/6vJZf/1/

```
       {
            text: 'Block Date',
            dataIndex: 'date',
            xtype: 'datecolumn',
            format: 'd/m/Y',
            editor: {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                allowBlank: true,
                format: 'd/m/Y'
            } 
        }
```

Comment: That's not working :(. I want my date cell will be block if that cell have block = true, but in my code that's only block in first time?

Comment: I think you don't understand my question. Please see my edit. I just explain my problem

Comment: I think your are right. Take a look at my other answer below.